# How to use more than 1 framework in Header search paths?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm using the framework from facebook...Then, my Framework search path is:

> /Users/Documents/MyProject/FacebookSDK $(SRCROOT)/../../FacebookSDK
>   $(SRCROOT)

And my header search paths

> ../facebook-iphone-sdk/src

Now I need to add $(inherited) "$(SRCROOT)/.." in framework searchPaths to use the Google Plus frameworks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you're asking about, click the "+" at the bottom of the window to add new frameworks adjacent to the `inherited` ones:

[image]

Comment: when I press + it open another line and when I add an value, change all the others

Comment: What do you mean "change all the others"? Are you adding this new path to your project or a target?